# Appium (iOS) how to choose two UITableCells with the same name

Tags: ios, ruby, appium, cucumber

I am using Appium and Cucumber with Ruby to carry out some UI tests on our application. I want to use the code below to select a button, with the same name but found in two different cells, for example cell 1 and cell 2. I do not want to use Xpath for this, I would really prefer to stick to using name.

Then(/^I click 'Like' on first file$/) do
  find_element(:name, "Like").click
end

Then(/^I click 'Like' on second file$/) do
  find_element(:name, "Like").click
end

Does anybody have any ideas on how to achieve this? Using each of these lines of code will only interact with the first button, and I would like a way to be able to interact with any of the 'Like' buttons in the Table Cells without resorting to Xpath.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find_elements(:name,"Like")[0].click
find_elements(:name,"Like")[1].click
...

button(1).click
button(2).click
...

ele_index(:UIAButton,1).click
ele_index(:UIAButton,2).click
...

buttons[0].click
buttons[1].click
...
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation to your answer, explaining how this helps the poster?

Comment: Indeed for programmers this will make sense, but maybe not for testers with only very basic programming skills.

Comment: Those are the ruby alternatives with appium to achieve what user asked. He already mentioned find_element(:name, "Like").click so he his familiar with appium/ruby. Hope my answer help others.